# Appending Ajax response to html with Jinja2 template (Google App Engine)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am iterating posts to display all the blog posts on my template using Jinja2. For each post, I want to append temperature data received from Ajax request but the formatting is not being properly displayed.

```
<div>
    {% for p in posts %}
        {{p.content | safe}}<br>
        <div id="info"></div>
            <script>
                var tempURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=APIKEY&q=' + {{p.city}} + '&units=metric';

                $.getJSON(tempURL, function(data){
                var temp = data.main.temp;

                $("#info").append(temp)
                });
            </script>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem so I can display temperature next to each post properly?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I certainly can see a problem arising with your use of `<div id='info'>`.  HTML only allows one element in the DOM to have a specific `id`, and your loop here is going to create more than one.  Try changing that to `<div class='info'>` instead.  You may also want to make sure that your JS is appending to the last element in the DOM with the class you specify.

Comment: Also seems a bit strange to get this data via hundreds of inidivdual Ajax requests to the API, especially as there's nothing interactive here. Rather, you should collect this data in the handler and pass it to the template in one go.

Comment: @coralv thanks for the feedback. It was en error and I changed the div id.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I will definitely try that . Thank you!